# What happens to the data when the pc suddenly shutdown during bitlocker encryption?

Tags: windows, bitlocker, disk-encryption

From what i read from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-deployment-and-administration-faq

it stated 
"What happens if the computer is turned off during encryption or decryption?
If the computer is turned off or goes into hibernation, the BitLocker encryption and decryption process will resume where it stopped the next time Windows starts. This is true even if the power is suddenly unavailable."

My qns if the bitlocker encryption is suddenly cut off during a power failure/suddenly shutdown. Is the data in the hdd still accessible? It is encrypted(partially?)? My main concern is will there be a scenario whereby the power is suddenly cut off during encryption and someone is able to retrieve the data since its not encrypted yet.

Answer (score 0):

During the *initial* encryption, any data on the hard drive that has not gone through the encryption process is still accessible.

Once the hard drive has finished being encrypted, no data will be accessible without authentication.

Comment: what if its 20% done only? so do u mean the 20% encrypted will be not accessible the rest of 80% will still be accessible? So the hdd itself is still readable

Comment: @user935892 yes

Comment: ok thanks! This is correct in a scenario where the pc encrypt half way, power shutdown, someone take out the hdd from the computer put into another pc or connect as a usb external device am i correct?

Comment: @user935892 - What you describe is not possible